# ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API And Overloads

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 4. I've created an endpoint. That endpoint is available at:

/myController/actionName

In my controller, I have the following defined:

[HttpPost]
public void ActionName(string parameter1)
{

}

I am trying to figure out if its possible to have overloads. In ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API, is there a way for me to say something like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public void ActionName(string parameter1)
{

}

[HttpPost]
public void ActionName(string parameter1, string parameter2)
{

}
```

If not, is there a way to make parameters optional?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot overload controller actions, however, you can specify a parameter to be optional when defining your routing as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "OptionalParameter",
    url: "myController/actionName/{parameter1}/{parameter2}",
    defaults: new { controller = "myController", action = "actionName", parameter1 = "Default Value", parameter2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```